# Binary search tree delete not working, why?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement Binary search tree in C.
But I am stuck at the delete operation, when I run the code it doesn't delete the value specified.

Before calling delete:(calling `inorder()`)

```
16 19 23
```

After calling delete:(calling `inorder()`)

```
16 19 23
```

code:

```
void deleteNode(struct node *n, int data)
{
     struct node *temp;
     if(n->data==data)
     {
       if(n->left == NULL && n->right == NULL)
       {
        n=NULL;
       }
       else if(n->left == NULL && n->right!=NULL)
       {
        n->data = (n->right)->data;
        n->right = NULL;
       }
       else if(n->left!=NULL && n->right == NULL)
       {
        n->data = (n->left)->data;
        n->left=NULL;
       }
       else if(n->left != NULL && n->right != NULL)
       {
        temp = findMax(root);
        n->data = temp->data;
        temp = NULL;
       }
     }
     else if(n->data > data)
     {
      deleteNode(n->left, data);
     }
     else if(n->data < data)
     {
      deleteNode(n->right, data);
     }
}
```

I have other code which is working, but I want to know what is wrong with this code?

**Edit:**
I have edited the code with a few changes in it.

Now, When I try to delete the ***ROOT*** node.
I end up with this:
(inorder traversal)-> `16 23 23`

Now, 
Why is this happening when `temp = NULL` is making the maximum node NULL.

Note: I am not initializing temp as the code has been changed and it is initialized just before its use (`temp = findMax(root)`).

code inorder():

```
void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
         inorder(root->left);
         printf("%d\n", root->data);
         inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code above you even don't initialize `temp`.

Comment: `n=NULL;` : This is no effect. `free(temp);` : `temp` is uninitalized.

Comment: Leave the implementation alone. Look at your function signature. Can it delete the root node?

Comment: Conceptually, in order to remove `n` from the tree (assuming that's what you're trying to do), you need to pass `n`'s parent to the function.

Comment: Can you try stepping through the code ?

Comment: Also try to see how you delete in a linked list. You don't just delete the node, right? You need to rearrange pointers on the sides of the list.

Comment: Throwing away entire subtrees is probably a bad idea. Draw some trees on paper and work out what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this alternative code or use your temp tree in your method

```
struct node *temp = n; //then use temp tree in code
```

Alternative method

```
struct node *delete(struct node *tree, int data)
{
    if(find(tree,data)==-1 || tree == NULL)
            return tree;

    if(tree->data == data)
        {   
            if(tree->left==NULL && tree->right==NULL)
               return NULL; 

            if(tree->right != NULL){
                tree->data = min(tree->right); 
                tree->right = delete(tree->right,min(tree->right)); 
                return tree;
            }

                tree->data = madata(tree->left); 
                tree->left = delete(tree->left,madata(tree->left)); 
                return tree;

        }

    if(tree->data < data)
    {
        tree->right= delete(tree->right,data);
        return tree;

    }

    tree->left= delete(tree->left,data);
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: My main question is what is exactly wrong with my code, can you explain it briefly?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me,

```
struct node* deleteNode(struct node *n, int data)
{
     struct node *temp;
     temp = n;
     if(n->data==data)
     {
       if(n->left == NULL && n->right == NULL)
       {
        n=NULL;
        return NULL;
       }
       else if(n->left == NULL && n->right!=NULL)
       {
        n = n->right;
        temp = NULL;
       }
       else if(n->left!=NULL && n->right == NULL)
       {
        n = n->left;
        temp = NULL;
       }
       else if(n->left != NULL && n->right != NULL)
       {
        temp = findMax(root);
        n->data = temp->data;
        temp = NULL;
       }
     }
     else if(n->data > data)
     {
      n->left = deleteNode(n->left, data);
     }
     else if(n->data < data)
     {
      n->right = deleteNode(n->right, data);
     }
     return n;
}
```